# ASP.NET Identity - Allow a change password on a social account?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We're building an app using ASP.Net Identity for authentication. We allow users to login using their Facebook or Google account. Or the user can create an account in our app.

We're implementing the password reset feature and came across an issue we're not quite sure how to handle. Say a user is using their social account to log in to our app. Should they even see the 'Forgot Password' link on our Login page, if they go there? It seems obvious this shouldn't even be an option for those users using their social account to log in, but we wanted to make sure we were not overlooking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user goes to login page he is most likely not authenticated, so how will you know if to hide the 'Forgot Password' link?

In ASP.Net Identity a user can have a local login AND external account logins at same time, its built in. So if a user logged in with an external account press 'Forgot Password', the framework will create a local login for that user with a 'reseted' password (he will not reset the external login). That user will end up having to 2 ways to login in his account.

If that should be an option? In my opinion, it should.

Answer (score 0):

How about change the password of the user if you have already collected the mobile number or the email id of the user so the reset password link can be sent to his/her email id and the password can now be reset.

Yes the user will be having two ways to login to the application.